# Table-cell allignment with in a blackout box

Tags: css

Here's my code:

```
.blackout {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none; /*This is changed by javascript to table */
}

.firstTime {
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: white;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10em;
    width: 20em;
}
```

The element itself is pretty straight forward... just a span with just text. I'm trying to center it in the middle, automatically sized. Nothing I'm doing is working. Any suguestions?

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/jNeeL/

Comment: can you post your HTML as well? or better yet, post it to a fiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: See fiddle in question...

Comment: thanks, now I am not clear on what you want to align to what - could you clarify please?

Comment: I want .firstTime to be in absolute center.

Comment: vertical and horizontal centre?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `text-align: center;` to `.blackout`.

Without knowing more about how your HTML is structured, it's hard to tell if that would be all you need to do.

**UPDATED:**

Also added `margin: auto` to `.firstTime` and removed `position:absolute`

Comment: well, I played a bit with the fiddle, updated version is here (http://jsfiddle.net/jNeeL/5/) not sure if this will be the centering you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather without html, you could absolute position the .firstTime class and set the top to 50% and left to 50%, then use negative top and left margin for half the height and width of the .firstTime object:

like so:

```
.blackout {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: none; /*This is changed by javascript to table */
}
.firstTime {
font-size: 18px;
background-color: white;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
height: 10em;
width: 20em;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin:-5em 0 0 -10em;
}
```

On my ipad so i have not tried this.

Comment: Thanks. However, to me it's messy, and ever since I found EM's I've been really trying to use those. I like how it can somehow be the same on every platform. It didn't work for me.

Comment: Or, using your example... http://jsfiddle.net/jNeeL/6/

I turned the display on so you can see.